# Playframework-1.2.4 Entity and SQL Server 2000, return 462 records instead of 8800 :S

Tags: java, sql-server-2000, playframework, entity, jtds

I have a problem with SQL Server 2000, I has been using jtds-1.2.5, I have 2 connections, Mysql is the principal, but I need access to MSSQL Info. The problem is when I make a "List alumnos = Salumnos.findAll();", this return 462 records instead of 8800 :S

I included my Entity and the table:

http://pastebin.ca/2104196

The Config is something like this:

```
db.url=jdbc:mysql://pruebas:9995/proyecta
db.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db.user=user
db.pass=******

db_saiiut.url=jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://pruebas/saiiut
db_saiiut.driver=net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver
db_saiiut.user=user
db_saiiut.pass=******
db_saiiut.jpa.debugSQL=true 
db_saiiut.jpa.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect
```

Cheers

Comment: you have debugSQL set to true : what happens if you take the request generated by the findAll method and execute it directly on mssql ? With specific id, you better have to inherit from GenericModel instead of Model

Answer (score 0):

Play! Documentation and Milestones out of synch. :(

Multi-db support was added to the ‘master’ branch, but has not been
included in the 1.2.x release branch. However, I mistakenly include
its documentation in the 1.2.3 release, and have since removed this
documentation for the upcoming 1.2.4 release (i.e. this issue is
already resolved).
Unfortunately, there is no firm schedule for the 1.3 release. Thanks
for raising this issue, in any case.